# Is there a way to programmatically determine that an image link is bad?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the site that I'm working on, the image displayed is not always (displayed) because the link could be bad or stale (or whatever). You can see it here: [Why is my dynamic HTML seemingly randomly placed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689644/why-is-my-dynamic-html-seemingly-randomly-placed)

When that happens, I want to be able to show an "Image Unavailable" message where the image would be. Is that possible? If so, two things are needed:

```
1) To be able to determine programmatically that the image is not being displayed
2) To replace it, in that case, with aforementioned message
```

Perhaps something like (pseudocode):

```
if (ImageMissing) {
    $('img').Attr('src', 'imageMissing.png');
}
```

?

### UPDATE

Okay, so the code should be like:

```
function doSomething() {
    var htmlBuilder = '';
    $.getJSON('duckbills.json', function() {
        // each ...
        // process the json file, building dynamic html
        htmlBuilder += 'img="bla.png"...';

        $('img').error(function() {
             $(this).attr("src", "imageMissing.png");
        });
    }):
}):
```

???

Does this cause each image, as it's added, to have that error handler attached to it, so that there are N event handlers bound, one for each image?

Or should it be:

```
function doSomething() {
    var htmlBuilder = '';
    $.getJSON('duckbills.json', function() {
        // each ...
        // process the json file, building dynamic html
        htmlBuilder += 'img="bla.png"...';
    }):
    $('img').error(function() {
         $(this).attr("src", "imageMissing.png");
    });
}):
```

???

### UPDATE 2

This is my code, and it doesn't work:

```
$.getJSON('Content/NBCCJr.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, dataPoint) {
        if (IsYear(dataPoint.category)) {
            htmlBuilder += '<div class=\"yearBanner\">' + dataPoint.category + '</div>';
        } else { 
            htmlBuilder += '<section class=\"wrapper\" ><a id=\"mainImage\" class=\"floatLeft\" href=\"' +
                dataPoint.imghref + '\"' + ' target=\"_blank\"><img height=\"160\" width=\"107\" src=\"' +
                dataPoint.imgsrc + '\"' +
                dataPoint.imgalt + '></img></a>' +
                '<div id=\"prizeCategory\" class=\"category\">' +
                dataPoint.category +
                '</div><br/><cite id=\"prizeTitle\" >' +
                dataPoint.title +
                '</cite><br/><div id=\"prizeArtist\" class=\"author\">' +
                dataPoint.author +
                '</div><br/>';
            if (dataPoint.kindle.trim().length > 2) {
                htmlBuilder += '<button><a href=\"' + Urlize(dataPoint.kindle) + '\"' +
                    ' target=\"_blank\">Kindle</a></button>';
            }
            if (dataPoint.hardbound.trim().length > 2) {
                htmlBuilder += '<button><a href=\"' + Urlize(dataPoint.hardbound) + '\"' +
                    ' target=\"_blank\">Hardbound</a></button>';
            }
            if (dataPoint.paperback.trim().length > 2) {
                htmlBuilder += '<button><a href=\"' + Urlize(dataPoint.paperback) + '\"' +
                    ' target=\"_blank\">Paperback</a></button>';
            }
            htmlBuilder += '</section>';                

        // Doesn't work
        $('img').error(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "Content/NoImageAvailable.png");
        });
    }
}); //each
```

...and I don't know why...

Comment: Is this image located on the same domain as the code that will be determining its existence?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263359/how-can-i-determine-if-an-image-has-loaded-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a crawler to go through your site and inform you of missing content?  Content is more likely to be non-existant due to permanent removal rather than temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure is, the [error()](http://api.jquery.com/error/) method :

```
$('img').error(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "imageMissing.png");
});
```

> The error event is sent to elements, such as images, that are
>   referenced by a document and loaded by the browser. It is called if
>   the element was not loaded correctly.

Comment: Can I add this to the function that dynamically generates the HTML, or does it have to be in the "ready" function? If the latter, does the "$(this)" portion have to change?

Comment: As long as the element is available (in the DOM) you can use it like any other handler. `this` refers to the image inside the function, how you use it is up to you I guess ?

Comment: It's not working for me; the area remains blank. I've got it in the ready function, above the getJSON() code.

Comment: What getJSON code? If the image are inserted dynamically, you would have to attach the error handler to them after or while they are inserted.