# How can I push the first row of images down?

Tags: jquery, css, html, dynamic

Thanks to SeanKendle over at [Why is my dynamic HTML seemingly randomly placed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689644/why-is-my-dynamic-html-seemingly-randomly-placed), I've made progress on the appearance of my site, but as you can see:

[image]

...it still needs some work, specifically that the first row needs to start below the tabs. How can I accomplish that? It doesn't seem like adding padding to the tab widget would help, as it is already being encroached on by the dynamically generated html, so I'm at a loss as to how to "push down" that first row.

The fundamental html, css, and jQuery can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/cMYEH/6/

...and the html generating code is like this:

```
$.getJSON('Content/NBCCJr.json', function (data) {
    // I tried renaming the above to nbcc.json, but it won't work with that name...?!? $.getJSON('Content/nbcc.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, dataPoint) {
        if (IsYear(dataPoint.category)) {
            htmlBuilder += '<div class=\"yearBanner\">' + dataPoint.category + '</div>';
        } else { // see snippet at top of unit for dealing with landscape-oriented books (such as some children's books) to change height and width of img
            htmlBuilder += '<section class=\"wrapper\" ><a id=\"mainImage\" class=\"floatLeft\" href=\"' +
                dataPoint.imghref + '\"' + ' target=\"_blank\"><img height=\"160\" width=\"107\" src=\"' +
                dataPoint.imgsrc + '\"' +
                dataPoint.imgalt + '></img></a>' +
                '<div id=\"prizeCategory\" class=\"category\">' +
                dataPoint.category +
                '</div><br/><cite id=\"prizeTitle\" >' +
                dataPoint.title +
                '</cite><br/><div id=\"prizeArtist\" class=\"author\">' +
                dataPoint.author +
                '</div><br/>';
            if (dataPoint.kindle.trim().length > 2) {
                htmlBuilder += '<button><a href=\"' + Urlize(dataPoint.kindle) + '\"' +
                    ' target=\"_blank\">Kindle</a></button>';
            }
            if (dataPoint.hardbound.trim().length > 2) {
                htmlBuilder += '<button><a href=\"' + Urlize(dataPoint.hardbound) + '\"' +
                    ' target=\"_blank\">Hardbound</a></button>';
            }
            if (dataPoint.paperback.trim().length > 2) {
                htmlBuilder += '<button><a href=\"' + Urlize(dataPoint.paperback) + '\"' +
                    //'class=\"float-right\" target=\"_blank\">Paperback</a></button>';
                    ' target=\"_blank\">Paperback</a></button>';
            }
            htmlBuilder += '</section>';
        }
    }); //each
    $('#BooksContent').append(htmlBuilder);
```

I added this to section.wrapper in the CSS:

```
padding-top:25px;
```

...but I still have, as you can see, that encroachment upwards of the first row of dynamic html. Do I need to add something to the CSS regarding the tab widget, or alter the generation of html, or...???

Comment: Perfect - make it an answer, and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `padding-top` try `margin-top` and see if it's any different. Padding would just expand the background since it's padded inside, the margin should lower the entire thing.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the fiddle looks good. Did u make any changes, and if u want the books to start from next row after the year, than just remove the float:left property of '.yearBanner'

Apart from that i don't see any wrong alignments there. If u have a different version as your screenshot try setting the position:relative, and then use the top:25px property.

Can you brief your problem more clearly and give us a fiddle to show your exact problem. If i am missing something, excuse me.